# Huawei IME and input language

Tags: keyboard, languages

I've encountered a problem using my Huawei U8350 Boulder powered by Android 2.2.2. The phone has physical keyboard and I would like to switch between different keyboard layouts (or input languages) while browsing. I have two input methods one is Huawei IME and Android keyboard. I checked forums and they suggests to find "Input languages" in "Android Keyboard" settings which is unavailable on my phone.

However Huawei IME is very handy and has a hotkey to switch between input languages, but it looks like it works for Chinese only, because when I switch it to, for example, Russian it still uses English letters.

Maybe someone encountered such problem and knows the answer?